# Changing tags that have only <label> tag within <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html structure

```
<ul>
<li> 
    Text <label>1#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
    <li> 
    Text <label>2#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
    <li> 
    Text <label>3#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
    <li> 
    Text <label>4#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
    <li> 
    Text <label>5#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
<li> 
  <label>6#</label> 
</li>
   <label>7#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>  
</ul>
```

I need to break this structure starting `<ul>` li which has just `<label>` inside tag. End result would be that

```
<ul>
    <li>Text
        <label>1#</label>
        <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
    <li>Text
        <label>2#</label>
        <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
    <li>Text
        <label>3#</label>
        <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
    <li>Text
        <label>4#</label>
        <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
    <li>Text
        <label>5#</label>
        <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- DIVIDE -->
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>6#</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>7#</label>
        <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to use some combination of `.replace();` no further attempt worked. Is it possible to do this?

**[DEMO CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/FGJLg/2/)**

Comment: Sure. What have you tried?

Comment: Each `label` should be associated with the corresponding inputs either by placing the input inside the `label` or using the `for` attribute.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Comment: @isherwood My code http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/FGJLg/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
$("ul>li:not(:has(:not(label)))").each(function() {
    var li = $(this);   
    var newUl = $(document.createElement("ul"));
    li.parent().after(newUl);
    li.nextAll("li").andSelf().appendTo(newUl);
});
```

This works with multiple separators.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LucasTrz/hWjLB/

Comment: How do I share my after he `<ul>` code `<li>` remove it? (Example: `<label>` `<ul>` 6 # `</ label>` ........)

Comment: Err... sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat unclear what the desired outcome is, and also note that your HTML is broken: there is a missing opening `li` tag for element #7. So, assuming that you want to move out the first `li` that does not have an `input` and all `li` elements after that one, and place those `li` elements in a separate (new) `ul`, here's the code:

```
var x = $('<ul>').insertAfter('ul');
var y = $('ul li:not(:has(>input))');
var z = $(y).nextAll();
$(y).appendTo(x);
$(z).appendTo(x);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FGJLg/3/

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
// select all the label elements:
$('label')
// filter that collection:
.filter(function () {
    // keeping only those 'label' elements that have no siblings:
    return $(this).siblings().length === 0;
})
// moving to the closest ancestor 'li' elements of those 'label' elements:
.closest('li')
// adding a specific class (for the next part):
.addClass('labelOnly')
// selecting all elements that follow, until another element with the added
// class-name is found:
.nextUntil('li.labelOnly')
// adding the original 'li' back to the selection:
.addBack()
// wrapping those 'li' elements in a 'ul':
.wrapAll('<ul></ul>')
// 'wrapAll()' returns the original (wrapped) elements, we use 'parent()'
// to get to the 'ul':
.parent()
// and append it to the body:
.appendTo('body');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FGJLg/6/).

References:

- [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li:not(:has(> input))').each(function () {
    var myList = $(this).parent('ul');
    var myEls = $(this).nextAll('li').andSelf();
    myEls.remove();
    myList.after(myEls);
    myEls.wrapAll('<ul>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/asn4L

Comment: Updated for new understanding of OP's question.